# Sharing the same application interface to a GUI and a debug shell

Tags: c++11, model-view-controller, ipc, rpc

I am developing a cross platform application (OS X, Linux, Windows) in C++11 that should provide a custom *debug shell* as an external application.

This debug shell is used to invoke methods that are exposed by the public interface of the application. Mainly it should allow to perform the same operations that are available from the app GUI.

Debug shell and application will run on the same machine (remote access would be a plus, so it is not necessary).

I was wondering which approach I could use to assure portability (different OS), performance and code reuse (I would like to share the same *model* for GUI and debug shell).

My first idea was to use [gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc) and [Google Protocol Buffer](https://github.com/google/protobuf) to access to the application interface from both GUI and debug shell, but I am afraid that such solution would add performance and design overhead.

Do you have any design and technical suggestion about?

Answer (score 0):

gRPC should be fine for this use.

On Mac and Linux you could make use of unix domain sockets to do this.

Since you want to be portable to Windows too, you'd be better off binding to localhost, as is done in the helloworld examples in the github repository: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp/helloworld.

gRPC uses very little CPU while nothing is happening, and the serialization and network overhead in making a request will be well within interactive usage latencies (expect 100's of microseconds at worst).